# User keybindings - return 'letter/symbol' combination not command

Tags: r, sublimetext3, key-bindings

I want to create a custom keybinding in sublime text 3 that doesn't return a command but returns the key combination used in R to define a variable like below.

```
variable <- variable_definition //for example
z1 <- seq(1,100)
```

In R 3.2.2 GUI mac OS X the keybinding:

```
"alt+-" returns " <- "
```

I have read the [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) for user keybindings but couldn't find something that I could use.
I have tried "print" and "echo" as below but they don't work.

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+-"], "print": " <- "}
]
```

or

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+-"], "echo": " <- "}
]
```

Some help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime Text you run commands with arguments. If you want to insert something the command is `insert` and the argument is called `characters`. If you want to limit it to the language R you can add a context. Hence the keybinding:

```js
[
    {
        "keys": ["alt+-"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": " <- "},
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.r" }
        ]
    }
]
```

Aside: it could also be interesting for you to use [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) as keybindings.

```js
[
    {
        "keys": ["alt+-"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "${1:variable} <- ${0:definition}"}
    }
]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Now I feel bad I overlooked this.